# Can we pass sessions variables to the class

Tags: php, mysql, oop, session

I'm trying to pass session variables into the below class. However, it doesn't appear to be working, and throws the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\wamp\www\pard_config\configuration.php on line 6

How can I solve this?

My code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    class pardEngine{
        public $hostname = $_SESSION['HOSTNAME'];
        public $database = $_SESSION['DATABASE'];
        public $database_user = $_SESSION['USER'];
        public $database_user_pass = $_SESSION['PASSWORD'];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 9):

From the [Properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) manual page:

> Class member variables are called "properties". You may also see them
>   referred to using other terms such as "attributes" or "fields", but
>   for the purposes of this reference we will use "properties". They are
>   defined by using one of the keywords public, protected, or private,
>   followed by a normal variable declaration. **This declaration may
>   include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant
>   value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and
>   must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.**

Session data does not fit in the *compile time* category so your properties can only be set from regular code, either outside the class (since they are public) or from a method (maybe the constructor).

It's normally not practical to hard-code such values into a class code so I'd go for the constructor approach:

```
<?php

class pardEngine{
    private $hostname;
    private $database;
    private $database_user;
    private $database_user_pass;

    public function __construct($hostname, $database, $database_user, $database_user_pass){
        $this->hostname = $hostname;
        $this->database = $database;
        $this->database_user = $database_user;
        $this->database_user_pass = $database_user_pass;
    }
}


session_start();
$engine = new pardEngine($_SESSION['HOSTNAME'], $_SESSION['DATABASE'], $_SESSION['USER'], $_SESSION['PASSWORD']);
```

Answer (score 6):

Assign these properties in the `constructor` of this class and not like this.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign these values in the class declaration part.

Make use of constructor.

```
session_start();
class pardEngine{
        function __construct() {
             $hostname = $_SESSION['HOSTNAME'];
             $database = $_SESSION['DATABASE'];
             $database_user = $_SESSION['USER'];
             $database_user_pass = $_SESSION['PASSWORD'];

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a function that is able to create the object form an array:

```
class pardEngine
{
    public $hostname;
    public $database;
    public $database_user;
    public $database_user_pass;

    /**
     * @param array $array
     * @return partEngine
     */
    public static function createFromArray($array) {
        $obj                     = new static;
        $obj->hostname           = $array['HOSTNAME'];
        $obj->database           = $array['DATABASE'];
        $obj->database_user      = $array['USER'];
        $obj->database_user_pass = $array['PASSWORD'];

        return $obj;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
session_start();
$engine = pardEngine::createFromArray($_SESSION);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
class pardEngine{
  public function __construct(){
    $hostname = $_SESSION['HOSTNAME'];
    $database = $_SESSION['DATABASE'];
    $database_user = $_SESSION['USER'];
    $database_user_pass = $_SESSION['PASSWORD'];
   }
  }
```